How do webflux’s elastic schedulers works with database operations?
We have an application which was written by a different team with Webflux. As I can see there are some refinement points in the code, but my other team members doesn't agree on the refactor.
It is said that blocking functions should be called with Mono.fromCallable, now in the codebase Mono.just is used for calling blocking codes, like
.flatMap(something -> Mono.just(repository.get(id)))
After refactoring the code would be like this:
// the beginning of the chain doesn't matter
.flatMap(k ->
            Mono.fromCallable(() -> repository.get(id)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
)
// here we manipulate the p, that part is missing

//
.flatMap(p ->
            Mono.fromCallable(() -> repository.save(p)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
           .thenReturn(something)
)
.flatMap(something ->
            Mono.fromCallable(() -> repository.get(id)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
)
.flatMap(p -> doSomething);

All the repository calls are blocking calls.
In the chain we do the following

we get an object by an id

do some manipulation on the object

save the object

get the object from the database again.


Does the object be persisted before we get it from the database or we could get outdated data?
My understanding is that the chain goes further only when the operation finishes, but I like to verify this.

It is said that blocking functions should be called with Mono.fromCallable this is not true. The most important part is that you need to place the call on their own scheduler as you have done. and onSubscribe means it will affect the entire chain, so you dont need multiple onSubscribe calls, one per chain is enough as the docs state
